# Sync dataview with database

Tags: javascript, ajax, slickgrid

I'm using Slickgrid with Dataview to edit tables with up to 5000 rows, getting the data from a MySQL database using Laravel. I have created an AJAX save function that saves all the data to the database but this runs extremely slowly and freezes the grid for a few seconds:

```
function TestSave() {

    var request;
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/est/public/estimate/{{ $id }}",
        type: "PATCH",
        dataType: "json",
        params: {_token:token},
        async: true,
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(dataView.getItems()), _token:token
        }
    });

}
```

Is there a way of saving the data without it freezing? I thought of using grid.onClick or onBeforeEditCell and saving each row individually when it changes, but functions like inserting a row change the "order" value on every row below the insert.

What is the best way to keep the Dataview and database in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex issue.
Firstly, the ajax call should be asynchronous, so it shouldn't block for 5 seconds.
However if you are passing all 5000 rows to the server, then the JSON encoding could be taking a while. You are best only passing changed rows to the server.
However that in itself is a lot more complex that it at first seems.

You might be best using an existing framework to handle the data for you.
Breeze is a good choice.